# How to process jquery ajax requests in the order they were requested

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a java servlet page that checks a list of domain names and it checking each name through a jquery ajax request.  It works fine except the results are being appended to the DOM out of order.  What is the best method to process requests in the requested order but also be asynchronously like a long polling effect. I am new with javascript.

This is the code I am using for the requests:

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    type:'GET',
    url:servlet,
    success:function(data){
        $('p').append(data+"<br>");
    }, 
});
```

I was thinking of sending a sequence number to the java servlet which would return it through JSON but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Comment: you got a stray `,` after `success`. just saving you from future bugs.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to go ahead and create containers for each response right before you make the AJAX request, and then just have the callback use that container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is create the containers for the response ahead of time and then bind the callback around it (not actually binding as in the bind() function).

For example, assuming you have a container something like `<div id="container"></div>`, you can do the following:

```
function makeRequest(something) {
    var target = $("<div></div>");
    $("#container").append(target);
    $.get("", {something: something}, function(data) {
        target.html(data);
    });
}
```

It's a rather bad example in terms of flexibility, but it should illustrate the point.  It adds a div to the container before the request is made and then uses that div to push the response into.  That means that the divs will be appended in the order the requests are made.  You could extend this idea to use styling to make it look like the divs aren't there until they're populated, or you could have a "Loading" message in them.

(Also, the data passing is rather bad with the `something` parameter, but hopefully you get the point.)

Comment: I got this to work thanks!  I have a counter running and I use that counter to append a attr name to the div and in the success I did a DOM query for the div with that counter.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your problem is that the browser sends as many AJAX requests as possible to the server, and the server answers them as it can.  It's likely that the server is just answering some faster than others so you get them out of order though the requests were sent in order.

The fix for this would be to have your queries sent sequentially to ensure the answers back are sequential.  Essentially, do an AJAX call, and on success of that call, you then initiate the second AJAX call, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could sequence the requests sent to the server, caching the results, and adding them only in sequence

```
next_to_request = 0;
next_to_append = 0;
results = [];
function reqToServer(){
  var e = next_to_request++;

  $.ajax({
    async:true,
    type:'GET',
    url:servlet,
    success:function(data){
        results[e] = data;
    }, 
  }); 
function loadAnswers(){
   if (results[next_to_request]){
     data = results[next_to_request];
     next_to_request++;
     $('p').append(data+"<br>");
   }
}

setTimeout(100, loadAnswers);
```

This has a different thread for displaying the results, and are only displayed in the right order.

Comment: favorite solution with caching in an array, but why do you need the setTimeOut?

Answer (score 0):

Take the success functions out of the Ajax function itself, and chain the success functions, they will fire in order and if one request has not finished it will wait for it to finish before firing the next one.

A really simple way of doing it would be to just do like so:

```
var firstOne = $.ajax({
    async:true,
    type:'GET',
    url:servlet
}); 

var SecondOne = $.ajax({
    async:true,
    type:'GET',
    url:servlet
}); 

firstOne.done(function(data){
    $('p').append(data+"<br>");
    SecondOne.done(function(data){
        $('p').append(data+"<br>");
    }); 
});
```

For more advanced methods learning how [promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) work is a good idea!

This is much faster than sequentially sending ajax requests, waiting for the last one to finish before the next one starts, as this will send all of them when the browser is available, and chaining the done() functions will wait for any that are not finished, and just execute the ones that are finished right away when they are reached in the order you put them in, and the content will then be appended in the right order. If doing many ajax calls, using promises and $.when/$.then will let you build a more rational function with iterations etc.